# Sharepoint AD profile editor

Tags: web-part

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 Standard and wanted to know how its possible to alter the Active Directory profile of users. Sharepoint has a Profile Service which i havent used, I dont know if this can help me. I assume I need a webpart, and looked around the internet. I've found a few but they charge. Dont think I will convince company to pay for it!. Does anyone know of any free webparts I can use to accomplish this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking at syncing from SharePoint too AD certain/all profile fields? If so this is OOTB functionality, however in 2010 it is a 1 way at a time process, it updates on edit only there is no CRUD mechanism. If you want full syncing you would need a bought web part or make sacrifices in the companies plans. I don't know of a free web part for this, and I doubt someone would give such a nugget away for free.

Comment: hi. looking at presenting a form in Sharepoint to user and editing fields and this will update AD and visa versa. Dont understand '1 way at a time process', is it one way only ?

Comment: Yes, it is a one way process, you can select fields to update from or update too AD, but not both ways in 2010, this I believe is in 2013 however.